# binary semaphores implementation pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

Can someone see if have not made some stupid mistakes in the binary semaphore implementation? I know that some more checks have to be added but I have eventually lost the initial idea in the details.

```
/**
 * @brief Print an error message with additional information about the source code location.
 *
 * This function formats and prints an error message to the standard error stream (stderr) with
 * additional information about the function and line where the error occurred.
 *
 * @param message A null-terminated string containing the main error message to be printed.
 * @param line An integer representing the line number where the error occurred.
 * @param function A null-terminated string containing the name of the function where the error occurred.
 *
 * @note This function makes use of the `perror` function to print the error message along with the
 * additional information.
 *
 * @warning Make sure to use this function in places where the error handling and reporting are required.
 * It provides valuable information about the source code location of the error.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   if (error_condition) {
 *       printError("An error occurred in my_function.", __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
 *   }
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see perror()
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   printError("An error occurred in my_function.", __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @note It's important to note that the `message` parameter should be a format string with placeholders
 * for the function name and line number. For example: "An error occurred in %s (Function:%s Line:%d)".
 * The `function` and `line` parameters should be appropriately provided to replace the placeholders.
 * The format string is internally used with `snprintf` to create the final error message.
 *
 * @note The function calculates the necessary buffer size for the error message dynamically,
 * so it is important to ensure that the memory for the error message is allocated and freed properly.
 * The function allocates memory for the error message using the stack. The buffer size is calculated
 * based on the length of the message, function name, and line number, so there's no risk of buffer overflow.
 *
 * @warning Using this function with a format string containing placeholders is essential for the function to work as expected.
 *
 * @attention The provided format string should contain placeholders for the function name and line number,
 * and the function and line parameters should be correctly provided to replace these placeholders.
 * Failure to do so may result in incorrect error messages.
 *
 * @see snprintf()
 *
 * @return void
 */
static void printError(const char *message, int line, const char *function)
{
    int numChars = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s (Function:%s Line:%d)", message, function, line);
    char m[numChars + 1];

    snprintf(m, numChars + 1, message, function, line);
    perror(m);
}

/**
 * @brief Add milliseconds to a struct timespec.
 *
 * This function adds the specified number of milliseconds to a given struct timespec.
 *
 * @param ts A pointer to the struct timespec to which the milliseconds will be added.
 * @param ms An unsigned integer representing the number of milliseconds to add.
 *
 * @return A pointer to the updated struct timespec. If `ts` is NULL, the function returns NULL.
 *
 * @note The function modifies the `ts` parameter to reflect the addition of milliseconds.
 * @note The `timespec` structure is commonly used for representing time intervals, and it has fields for seconds and nanoseconds.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   struct timespec myTime = {0, 0};
 *   struct timespec* result = timespecAddMs(&myTime, 500);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see timespec, struct timespec
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   struct timespec myTime = {0, 0};
 *   struct timespec* result = timespecAddMs(&myTime, 500);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @note The function performs the addition of milliseconds by updating the `tv_sec` (seconds) and `tv_nsec` (nanoseconds) fields of the timespec structure.
 *
 * @attention It is essential to ensure that the `ts` parameter points to a valid struct timespec before calling this function. If `ts` is NULL, the function returns NULL without any modification.
 *
 * @attention The function assumes that `ms` is a non-negative integer value. Negative values for `ms` may result in unexpected behavior.
 *
 * @see struct timespec
 *
 * @return A pointer to the updated struct timespec, or NULL if `ts` is NULL.
 */
static struct timespec *timespec_addms(struct timespec *ts, unsigned ms)
{
    uint64_t nsec;
    if(ts)
    {
        ts -> tv_sec += ms / 1000;
        nsec = ts -> nsec + (ms % 1000) * 1000000ULL;
        ts -> tv_sec += msec / 1000000000ULL;
        ts -> tv_nsec = msec % 1000000000ULL;
    }
    return ts;
}

/**
 * @brief Lock a pthread mutex with a specified timeout.
 *
 * This function attempts to lock a pthread mutex with an optional timeout. It allows for immediate
 * (non-blocking), maximum wait (blocking), or timed blocking lock operations.
 *
 * @param mutex A pointer to the pthread mutex to be locked.
 * @param wait An unsigned integer indicating the type of lock operation. Use SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT for immediate,
 * SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT for maximum wait, or any other positive value for a timed lock with the specified timeout in milliseconds.
 *
 * @return 0 if the mutex is successfully locked, or an error code if the lock operation fails.
 *
 * @note The function makes use of the `clock_gettime` and `timespecAddMs` functions to calculate the timeout
 * based on the current time and the specified wait duration.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
 *   int result = mutex_lockwait(&myMutex, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see pthread_mutex_t, clock_gettime(), timespecAddMs()
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
 *   int result = mutex_lockwait(&myMutex, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @attention It is essential to ensure that the `mutex` parameter points to a valid pthread mutex before calling this function.
 * Using an uninitialized or invalid mutex may lead to undefined behavior.
 *
 * @attention The `wait` parameter must be set to one of the predefined values (SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT) or a positive integer representing the timeout in milliseconds. Using negative values may result in unexpected behavior.
 *
 * @attention The function handles error conditions and, in the case of a lock failure, it can call `printError` to print an error message with information about the error location.
 *
 * @note The function checks if `mutex` is not NULL and returns EFAULT if it is. This ensures proper error handling for invalid or uninitialized mutexes.
 *
 * @see pthread_mutex_t, printError()
 *
 * @return 0 if the mutex is successfully locked, or an error code if the lock operation fails.
 */
static int mutex_lockwait(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, unsigned wait)
{
    int result = 0;
    int line;
    struct timespec timeOut;

    if(mutex)
    {
        if(result = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeOut))
        {
            line = __LINE__;
            goto exit_cleanup;
        }

        timespec_addms(&timeOut, wait);

        switch(wait)
        {
            case SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT:
                result = pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex);
                line = __LINE__;
                break;
            case SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT:
                result = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
                line = __LINE__;
                break;
            default:
                result = pthread_mutex_timedlock(mutex, &timeOut);
                line = __LINE__;
                break;
        }
    }
    else result = EFAULT;

    exit_cleanup;
    if(result)
    {
        if(result != EBUSY)
        {
            printError("[MUTEX]", line, __FUNCTION__);
        }
    }
    return result;
}





void binarySemaphoreDestroy(binary_semaphore_t *s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        pthread_cond_destroy(&s -> cvar);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&s -> mutex);
        free(s);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Calculate the time difference between two struct timespec values.
 *
 * This function calculates the time difference in nanoseconds between two struct timespec values (t1 - t2).
 *
 * @param t1 A pointer to the first struct timespec value (later time).
 * @param t2 A pointer to the second struct timespec value (earlier time).
 *
 * @return An int64_t representing the time difference in nanoseconds. If t1 is not later than t2, the function returns -1.
 *
 * @note The function assumes that t1 represents a later time than t2.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   struct timespec startTime, endTime;
 *   int64_t timeDifference = timespec_diff(&endTime, &startTime);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see struct timespec
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   struct timespec startTime, endTime;
 *   int64_t timeDifference = timespec_diff(&endTime, &startTime);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @attention It is important to ensure that the provided struct timespec values are valid and represent time correctly. The function assumes that t1 represents a later time than t2.
 *
 * @attention The function returns -1 if t1 is not later than t2, indicating an invalid input.
 *
 * @return An int64_t representing the time difference in nanoseconds, or -1 if t1 is not later than t2.
 */
static int64_t timespec_diff(const struct timespec *t1, const struct timespec *t2)
{
    int64_t nanodiff = -1;
    //t1 has to be later than t2
    if(t1 -> tv_sec >= t2 -> tv_sec)
    {
        nanodiff = (t1 -> tv_sec - t2 -> tv_sec) * 1000000000ULL; 
        if(t1 -> tv_nsec > t2 -> ntv_sec)
        {
            nanodiff += t1 -> tv_nsec - t2 -> ntv_sec;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!nanodiff) 
            {
                nanodiff = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                nanodiff -= 1000000000ULL + (t1 -> tv_nsec - t2 -> ntv_sec);
                
            }
        }
    }
    return nanodiff;
}

/**
 * @brief Convert a duration in nanoseconds to a struct timespec.
 *
 * This function converts a duration in nanoseconds to a struct timespec value, which represents time in seconds and nanoseconds.
 *
 * @param nanosec An int64_t value representing the duration in nanoseconds to be converted.
 *
 * @return A struct timespec value representing the equivalent time duration in seconds and nanoseconds.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   int64_t durationInNanoseconds = 1500000000LL;
 *   struct timespec timeValue = nanoToTimespec(durationInNanoseconds);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see struct timespec
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   int64_t durationInNanoseconds = 1500000000LL;
 *   struct timespec timeValue = nanoToTimespec(durationInNanoseconds);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @attention It is important to ensure that the `nanosec` parameter is a non-negative int64_t value.
 *
 * @return A struct timespec value representing the equivalent time duration in seconds and nanoseconds.
 */
static struct timespec nanoToTimespec(int64_t nanosec)
{
    return (struct timespec){.tv_sec = nanosec / 1000000000ULL, .tv_nsec = nanosec % 1000000000ULL};
}


/**
 * @brief Wait for a binary semaphore with an optional timeout.
 *
 * This function waits for a binary semaphore, allowing a thread to block until the semaphore is posted (set).
 *
 * @param p A pointer to the binary semaphore structure.
 * @param wait An unsigned integer indicating the type of wait operation:
 * - Set to SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT for immediate (non-blocking) wait.
 * - Set to SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT for maximum wait (blocking).
 * - Set to any other positive value for a timed wait with the specified timeout in milliseconds.
 *
 * @return 0 if the binary semaphore is successfully acquired, or an error code if the operation fails or times out.
 *
 * @note The function first locks the binary semaphore's associated mutex and checks if the semaphore is already set (v is true).
 * If it's set, the function clears the semaphore (v becomes false) and unlocks the mutex, allowing the caller to proceed.
 * If not set, the function enters a loop to potentially wait for the semaphore to be set. If `wait` is SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT, the function immediately returns an error if the semaphore is not set. If `wait` is SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT, it blocks indefinitely until the semaphore is set. If `wait` is a positive value, it waits for the specified timeout and returns an error if the semaphore is not set within the specified time.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   struct binary_semaphore mySemaphore;
 *   int result = binarySemaphoreWait(&mySemaphore, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see binary_semaphore, mutex_lockwait(), timespec_diff(), timespec_addms(), pthread_cond_timedwait(), pthread_mutex_unlock()
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   struct binary_semaphore mySemaphore;
 *   int result = binarySemaphoreWait(&mySemaphore, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @attention It is essential to ensure that the `p` parameter points to a valid binary semaphore structure before calling this function.
 * Using an uninitialized or invalid structure may lead to undefined behavior.
 *
 * @attention The `wait` parameter must be set to one of the predefined values (SEMAPHORE_NOWAIT, SEMAPHORE_MAXWAIT) or a positive integer representing the timeout in milliseconds. Using negative values may result in unexpected behavior.
 *
 * @return 0 if the binary semaphore is successfully acquired, or an error code if the operation fails or times out.
 */
int binarySemaphoreWait(struct binary_semaphore *p, unsigned wait)
{
    //todo ADD timeouts.
    int result;
    
    struct timespec ts, ts1;
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    if((result = mutex_lockwait(&p -> mutex, wait))) goto cleanup_exit;
    while (!p->v)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts1);
        int64_t nandiff = timespec_diff(&ts1, &ts);
        if(nanodiff > 0 && (nanodiff / 1000000ULL) < wait)
        {
            timespec_addms(&ts, wait - nanodiff / 1000000ULL);
            pthread_cond_timedwait(&p->cvar, &p->mutex, &ts);
        }
    }
    p->v = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->mutex);

    cleanup_exit:
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Post (signal) a binary semaphore.
 *
 * This function posts (signals) a binary semaphore, allowing another thread to acquire it if it was in a wait state.
 *
 * @param p A pointer to the binary semaphore structure.
 *
 * @return 0 if the binary semaphore is successfully posted, or an error code if the operation fails.
 *
 * @note The function first locks the binary semaphore's associated mutex and checks if the semaphore is already set (v is true).
 * If it's set, the function returns EAGAIN to indicate that the semaphore is already posted. If not, it sets the semaphore (v becomes true)
 * and signals the associated condition variable (cvar) to potentially wake up a waiting thread.
 *
 * @code
 *   // Example usage:
 *   struct binary_semaphore mySemaphore;
 *   int result = binarySemaphorePost(&mySemaphore);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see binary_semaphore, pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_cond_signal(), pthread_mutex_unlock()
 *
 * @par Example:
 * @code
 *   struct binary_semaphore mySemaphore;
 *   int result = binarySemaphorePost(&mySemaphore);
 * @endcode
 *
 * @attention It is essential to ensure that the `p` parameter points to a valid binary semaphore structure before calling this function.
 * Using an uninitialized or invalid structure may lead to undefined behavior.
 *
 * @return 0 if the binary semaphore is successfully posted, or an error code if the operation fails.
 */
int binarySemaphorePost(struct binary_semaphore *p)
{
    int result = mutex_lock(&p -> mutex);

    if(result) goto cleanup_exit;
    if (p->v)
    {
        result = EAGAIN;
        goto cleanup_exit;
    }

    p->v = true;

    if((result = pthread_cond_signal(&p->cvar))) goto cleanup_exit;
    if((result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->mutex))) goto cleanup_exit;

    cleanup_exit:
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not pushed anywhere yet

Comment: A definition of `struct binary_semaphore` would be very helpful.

Comment: Aren't we missing some header files?